# Remove entire querystring using regex

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have the below regex, but how can I remove the querystring entirely if it is present:

```
^~/(.*)/restaurant/(.*)
```

eg. the url

```
/seattle/restaurant/sushi?page=2
```

or

```
/seattle/restaurant/sushi?somethingelse=something
```

or

```
/seatthe/restaurant/sushi
```

should just return `seattle` and `restaurant` and `sushi` and remove any querystring if it is present.

(sorry for reposting a similar question, but I couldn't get the answer to work in my previous question).

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This regex:

`(/[^?]+).*`

Should match the initial section of your URL and put it in a group.

So it will match `/seattle/restaurant/sushi` and put the value in a group.

You can use something like this: `(/.*?/restaurant[^?]+).*` if you want to handle just URLs with the word `restaurant` as the second word between the slashes.

Edit: Something like so should yield 3 groups: `/(.*?)/(restaurant)/([^?]+).*`. Group 1 being `seatthe`, group 2 being `restaurant` and group 3 being `sushi`. If after the last `/` there is a `?`, the regex discards the `?` and everything which follows.

Comment: I would like to match "seattle" and "sushi" as separate matches. Also if "sushi" is proceeded by a querystring. In which case I would like to match "sushi" and remove the ? and everything after that. Thanks

Comment: Excellent. That works! I tried removing the slash between the last two groups (restaurant) and ([^?]+).* because I would like it to match /seattle/restaurant?page=2 in the same way as /seattle/restaurant/sushi?page=2. But I couldn't get it to work. Since I have a lot of other URLs on the 2. level position like /seattle/restaurant-michelangelo, which should NOT be caught, I guess I need to hardcode the values on the 2. level which SHOULD be caught (eg. restaurant, cafe, take-away). At the third level (/seattle/restaurant/sushi) I don't have the problem, so your suggestion works here. Thanks

Comment: How do I modify the regex to match seattle and restaurant from the url /seattle/restaurant? Page =2 and discard the querystring ? I tried modifying the above but could not get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasD: I recommend you open a new question.

Comment: thanks. I opened a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145069/need-help-modifying-regex. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You should change your final `/./` to match "anything but a question mark" like this

```
^~/(.*)/restaurant/([^?]*)
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it partially works :-) I would still like it to return "sushi" even though "sushi" might be followed by a querystring. So eg a query like /seattle/restaurant/sushi?page=2 would match "seattle" and "sushi". Right now it seems it doesn't match "sushi" if it is proceeded by a querystring. Thanks