# regex to remove the querystring and match the remaining segments from the url

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

[npinti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243943/npinti) helped me create a regex to remove the querystring and match the remaining segments from the url `/seattle/restaurant/sushi?page=2`: "Something like so should yield 3 groups: `/(.*?)/(restaurant)/([^?]+).*.` Group 1 being seatthe, group 2 being restaurant and group 3 being sushi. If after the last /there is a ?, the regex discards the ? and everything which follows."

I have tried modifying the above to do the same trick on the url `/seattle/restaurant?page=2` but I could not get it right. I don't know if there will be af querystring or not or the parameters of the querystring. So I need the flexibility from the regex above which will match and discard the ? and everything which follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewriterules may look like:

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/restaurant/([^/]+)$ mynewpage.php?group1=$1&group2=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Your may search for what `QSA`, `NC`, and `L` mean thanks to the links I provide below.

---

I'm sorry but your question sound very like "I'm not very good, so can someone do the job for me?". I mean, just look around, you'll get a lot of answer, just get your hands dirty.

---

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Hi Olivier. You are right, I am not very skilled in regex, and I was hoping that it would be pretty straight forward for someone who knew regex to solve my problem. Anyway I dug into regex myself and managed to put something useful together using Expresso by http://www.ultrapico.com

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to match all text prior to the `?` and nothing else. It will match everything if no `?` is present:

```
[^?]*
```

Is that all you need to do? Because `/(.*?)/(restaurant)/([^?]+).*.` looks like it's designed to do something significantly more complicated.